# devise user sign_in gives authentication error for CSRF token authenticity token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, csrf, rails-api

I am using `devise` (latest version - 3.2.0) with `rails` (latest version - 4.0.1)

I'm doing simple authentication (without ajax or api) and getting an error for CSRF authenticity token. Check the POST request below

```
started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-08 19:48:49 +0530
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML

 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    
 "authenticity_token"=>"SJnGhXXUXjncnPhCdg3muV2GYCA8CX2LVFV78pqddD4=", "user"=> 
{"email"=>"a@a.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"},
"commit"=>"Sign in"}

Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
 User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" =  
'a@a.com' LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "current_sign_in_at" = ?,
"sign_in_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 2  [["last_sign_in_at", Fri,
08 Nov 2013 14:13:56 UTC +00:00], ["current_sign_in_at", Fri, 08 Nov 2013 14:18:49 UTC
+00:00], ["sign_in_count", 3], ["updated_at", Fri, 08 Nov 2013 14:18:49 UTC +00:00]]
(143.6ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 239ms (ActiveRecord: 144.5ms | Search: 0.0ms)
```

The root url points to `home#new`, which is like

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!
   def index
   end
end
```

Sign_in page generated html view is like:

- meta tags

  ```html
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
  <meta content="aV+d7Z55XBJF2VtyL8V3zupR3OwhaQ6UHNtlQLBQf5Y=" name="csrf-token" />
  ```
- form

  ```html
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/sign_in" class="new_user" id="new_user" 
  method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden
  value="aV+d7Z55XBJF2VtyL8V3zupR3OwhaQ6UHNtlQLBQf5Y=" />
  </div>
  <div><label for="user_email">Email</label><br />
  <input autofocus="autofocus" id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="email" value="" />
  </div>

  <div><label for="user_password">Password</label><br />
  <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" type="password" /></div>

  <div><input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0" />
  <input id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 
  <label for="user_remember_me">Remember me</label></div>

  <div><input name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in" /></div>
  </form>
  ```

The authentication request even updates the `last_sign_in_at` and `sign_in_count` values, but when I try to access `current_user` in controller it comes as `nil`.

According to me it is not actually signing in `user`. But then question comes "why it is updating `last_sign_in_at`/`sign_in_count` value in the `user` table ?"

Comment: I had months ago a similar issue and I could resolve with: Deleting all cookies and cache in my browser. Hope its for you as well

Comment: well, that may be the case. let me try.

Comment: It's not working even after clearing cache and cookies. I even trien in different browser.

Comment: Can you post your view for the registration page?  And also is '<%= csrf_meta_tags %>' in your application.html.erb file?

Comment: I've updated my question with generated views html code.

Comment: Did you see the posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986939/cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-in-rails , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040964/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-in-case-of-api-development , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362910/rails-warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-for-json-devise-requests ?

Comment: Yes. Those are for either AJAX request or api call related. Mine is simple html request as I mentioned in the question

Comment: Could you add the versions of devise and rails that you're using for future readers of this question?

Comment: Added version of rails and devise

Comment: Similar authentication issue. 
I think you can check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16264496/1915916

Comment: The case in link provided is that the request is made via curl
request. In my case it's made via form rendered by rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no problem with devise gem . I removed 'rails-api' gem and my app started working.

Comment: I don't have this Gem but I have the same problem

Comment: Try to remove some other gem and check if that corrects the problem or not. I am quite sure it is mostly coming because of some other gem

Comment: I'd love to hear which part of `rails-api` interfered with devise and how

Comment: Rails 5 has `rails-api` native, and now? =(

Comment: This is very old issue , I don't have the code base available in which I faced this issue .  I would not be able to give more details about this.

Answer (score 14):

When the CSRF token is not correct, Rails will not read or do any updates to the session. It will still do any other actions the controller specifies, which explains why you see the DB update but don't end up logged in.

I notice that the authenticity_token in your log and in your page do not match. I realize this just may be because you captured a different request, but you should check that the one on the page matches the one in the log for the same request. I'm also assuming that you are using the proper tag in your view which generates a different authenticity_token each time, and are not just hard-coding the HTML input.

Do you see the same issue with forms unrelated to devise? If not, as a workaround, you can exempt your action from the CSRF check with the following code in your controller:

```
protect_from_forgery except: :sign_in
```

The odds of a CSRF attack against your sign in action seems pretty remote (<-pun) to me.

Also, if it's just with devise, then I'd suggest you file an issue with them, [which you've already done](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2734).

Comment: log and form authenticity tokens are different because I added code for view/form part later to the question. I just checked it now and both are same, so I think that should not be the case for the above issue

Answer (score 5):

Add this on the Application Controller (this works on Rails 5)

```
protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }
```

Add this to the Devise SessionController

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:create]
```

Try it with curl

```
curl -X POST -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_in -d '{"user" : {"email": "name@mail.com", "password": "secret" }}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same issue just removing "remote: true" option in view:  changed form_for(model, remote: true) to form_for(model)