# Devise current_user = nil in ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here is the full error:

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 5  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 22ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `has_role?' for nil:NilClass:
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8:in `authenticate_admin_user!'
```

I can verify that I was logged in at the time with an admin user.

Here is the controller that is triggering the error:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def authenticate_admin_user!
    unless current_user.has_role? :admin
      flash[:alert] = "This area is restricted to administrators only."
      redirect_to main_app.root_path 
    end
  end
```

Comment: What request did you send to your app and how? It does look like you've missed a CSRF token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your application controller so that the current_user method will be defined

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed that issue.. but unfortunately now I am seeing Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't face this issue before, you can check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861402/devise-user-sign-in-gives-authentication-error-for-csrf-token-authenticity-token) it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Change
`unless current_user.has_role? :admin`

To this:
`unless current_user.try(:has_role?, :admin)`

What that does it it'll `try` calling the `:has_role?` method (with the `:admin` parameter, but instead of raising an exception it'll return `nil`.

Comment: But the problem is that current_user should be defined

Comment: sorry, but i didn't face this issue before, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861402/devise-user-sign-in-gives-authentication-error-for-csrf-token-authenticity-token), it might help