# Cypress : Getting "The change you wanted was rejected." message in chrome after submitting form

Tags: javascript, node.js, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, cypress

**Getting: "The change you wanted was rejected." message in chrome after submitting the form:**

Env: Chrome version: 80, MAC

cypress version: 4:3:0

node: v13.2.0

**POST - https://app-staging.xxxxx.com/users/sign_in   cypress_runner.js:139697**

Response Code: **422 (Unprocessable Entity)**

Any help and pointers appreciated?

Comment: Hey this is the response from your backend server right?

Comment: @Y4glory Yes, But I am automating via UI.

Comment: Are you using an Nginx reverse proxy in your backend?

Comment: Yes, BEnd is a rails app(FE react) and I guess BE are using Nginx reverse proxy?

Comment: https://github.com/gocd/gocd/issues/5296

This issue I found is pretty similar to what you're facing. They concluded that the reverse proxy misconfiguration caused this issue.

Comment: I also found another stack exchange question relating to rails app and this particular error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451345/heroku-rails-devise-the-change-you-wanted-was-rejected/29451586

Comment: Thanks mate! but I am getting the same error in Firefox too :(